# Retrieve Cloud Firestore data

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, blazor

I am saving data into Google Cloud Firestore database from one application and want to read it in another application.

It looks like I am having some mismatch between two ways of working. I am saving data into database with following call:

```
await CrossCloudFirestore.Current.Instance.Collection("Records").AddAsync(newRecord);
```

Then I am having following method for getting data in another application:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAll<T>(CancellationToken ct) where T : IDataRecord
{
  CollectionReference collection = _fireStoreDb.Collection(_collection);
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await collection.GetSnapshotAsync(ct);
  return snapshot.Documents.Select(x => x.ConvertTo<T>()).ToList();
}
```

where `_collection = "Records";`

My Firebase database looks like this after couple of `CrossCloudFirestore.Current.` calls:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzHE1.png

After couple of investigations it looks like Document name is the problem? If I am not mistaken with custom created document name "record" `GetAll` method was able to get necessary data. Can somebody help to get this working and point at what I am doing wrong?

If My data on Firebase side looks like this `GetAll` method works fine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psrcx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in one of database fields, that was set to TimeSpan on C# side. Firebase was changing this TimeSpan property into MAP with sub-properties. As I was thinking already before to change this TimeSpan into double for holding amount of seconds. After this change everything seems to be working fine!